# Can I insert a Page into a view in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I have requirements to have an "Editable" region underneath the header, but above the content of views. I have several pages that I need to do this.

Is there are way to insert a Page by name into a view? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need looks a lot like a widget: create an html widget, put it in the appropriate zone for your placement and in the appropriate layer for it to appear only in the relevant pages (don't be afraid to create a custom layer if you need to). You won't even need to write any code to achieve this!

Read about managing widgets in the [orchard documentation](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-widgets).

Comment: This worked well I:

1. Add the BeforeContent Zone into the theme
<div id="editable-content">             
 @if (Model.BeforeContent != null)               
 {                   
   @Zone(Model.BeforeContent);     
 }            
</div>
2. Create a layer for each view
3. create a widget for each view and add it to the zone